# what is the meaning of 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5.1.1 3 ) in snmp?

Tags: java, printing, snmp

I wrote an SNMP application to test the printer status.

When I give `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.15` to check printer status I got this (`1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5.1.1  3`) as output.

```
newVars = comInterface.getMIBEntry(itemIDs);
```

If anyone knows, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is the library you use to perform the above operation. If you can convert your Java code to a sequence of operations that can repeat step by step on a MIB browser, then you should be able to interpret the meaning.

For example, `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.15` is a column named prtMarkerStatus in the prtMarkerTable, defined in PRINTER-MIB (original RFC is https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3805),

http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/Printer-MIB.html

Because it is a column, so I could hardly understand what you mean "When I give `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.15` to check printer status I got this (1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5.1.1 3) as output". What was the SNMP request on the wire? GET NEXT, GET BULK, or another? It is meaningless to send a GET with `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.15` as that's invalid.

The proper way to manage printers, is to fully digest RFC 3805, which documents what are the tables defined in it, and what all the columns mean. Once you understand how this MIB document models the printers, it should be fairly easy to write correct Java code to walk the tables and grab the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've given the OID `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.15`, which is apparently a request for printer marker information (according to [this site](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.15)).

Your response OID begins with `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5`, which appears to be the appropriate response, (according to [the same site](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.5)).

Not sure what the trailing `1.1` in your output OID is. Perhaps something unique to your printer?

The response `3` seems to match with "*toner*".

Comment: Many Thanks. But this request to test the current status of the printer. My question is here how can know the status is up and running or error.

Comment: @user2331844 I would suggest you contact your printer manufacturer to get advice on this matter.

Comment: @user2331844 I think Lex Li's answer is fairly comprehensive. Perhaps you should respond to him. Please don't assume someone will provide you a solution that will require no additional effort for you.

Answer (score 0):

The numeric strings are examples of *Object Identifiers*, used as a standard way of identifying many things, including companies, lightweight directory attribute types, health care information, etc.  The IANA maintains a registry tree; each number corresponds to a branch between nodes. These are formally defined using the ASN.1 standard.